# Database design with limited number of values per row

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm looking for the best practice to design my database.

I have a table "product_reviews" with product reviews with the following columns:
revID, revName, revText, revDate

Now I want add Pros and Cons to the product reviews. A product review can have at most 5 Pros and 5 Cons.

What's the best practice?
To add 10 columns (revPro1,revPro2 etc) to my existing product_reviews table or create a new seperate table for saving these pros and cons?

Comment: separate table. from your post i interpret that often a product will have varying pros and cons [ wont always use the 10 possible fields ] resulting lots of nulls. additionally it will be very ugly to access as you will have to check conditionally each pro1, pro2, etc. instead of a where clause on a join..

Comment: Add two more tables: one for Pros and one for Cons with foreign key `Product_review.ID`. Maximum numbers of Pros and Cons per one product review you can control by your software code.

Answer (score 1):

According to normalization rules you have to create separate table. Moreover I would suggest to have record per pros/cons in the table and not a table with columns 'pro1', 'pro2' etc. which is also about  normalization.

From practical point of view let's assume later you need to have more pros/cons per review. With this approach you won't need to change DB structure (which could be quite difficult after some time). Another example could be applying some text limitation to pros/cons - you have to apply it only to 1 column, not to 10...